# How to retrieve objects that inherit from APIObject using FuelSDK-Java

Tags: marketing-cloud, java, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve all sends from an account on salesforce and even though I can instantiate the client using:

```
 ETConfiguration configuration = new ETConfiguration();
 configuration.set("clientId", "########");
 configuration.set("clientSecret", "#######");

 ETClient client = new ETClient(configuration);
```

I'm not able to retrieve Send objects because they don't inherit from neither ETSoapObject or ETRestObject.

Is there another route to achieve it? I couldn't find any options where I use only my credentials and the fuelSDK-Java for it.
Something like:

```
client.retrieve(ETSend.class);
```